# logic in if statement flow in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x

```
def find_acronym():
    # if search term in database returns acronym and expansion
    for abbr, text in acronyms.items():
        if abbr == search_analyte.get():
            expansion.insert(0.0,'{0:>6}: {1: <10}\n'.format(abbr, text))
        elif str(search_analyte.get()) in text:
            expansion.insert(0.0,'{0:>6}: {1: <10}\n'.format(abbr, text))

    # if search term not in database , returns message DOES NOT WORK PROPERLY!     
    if search_analyte.get() not in text or abbr != search_analyte.get():
        expansion.insert(0.0,'"{0}"{1} \n {2}\n'.format(search_analyte.get(),' is  not in the database.','Add,if appropriate'))
```

I use this function to search through a dictionary of acronyms and their associated expanded meaning in the format `{ ACRONYM: text details, ACRONYM2: its test,...}`

The algorithm 'works in the sense that it retrieves the acronym and text for any search item, but it also **always** returns the text message from the last if condition meant to discover whether the item is in the database or not. I clearly am illogical or I don't understand how loops work in Python.

Comment: Did you mean to indent the last `if` to be inside the `for` loop perhaps? If you think it already is indented to that level in your editor, you are mixing tabs and spaces and need to fix that to fix your problem. Run `python -tt yourscript.py` to detect where you are doing this.

Comment: Your problem  is you have to indent the last if condition to make it come inside the for loop. Then everything will work properly. And btw, if does not signify loop, but a condition .

Comment: Putting the last condition inside the for loop will NOT work. You will then get the "is not in dictionary" message for every entry in the dictionary that doesn't match your search term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it now, the last test is running *after* the FOR loop has completed, so you can't compare against `abbr` and `text` usefully any more.

You want something like:

```
def find_acronym():

    found = False

    # if search term in database returns acronym and expansion
    for abbr, text in acronyms.items():
        if abbr == search_analyte.get():
            expansion.insert(0.0,'{0:>6}: {1: <10}\n'.format(abbr, text))
            found = True
        elif str(search_analyte.get()) in text:
            expansion.insert(0.0,'{0:>6}: {1: <10}\n'.format(abbr, text))
            found = True

    # if search term not in database    
    if not found:
        expansion.insert(0.0,'"{0}"{1} \n {2}\n'.format(search_analyte.get(),' is  not in the database.','Add,if appropriate'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Vicky. Works perfectly now and I shall apply this logic to my problems of 'seeing' where I go wrong using conditionals as well as loops. I can't even get the terminology right yet!

Comment: The Python for loop has a else clause that is executed when you don't break out of the loop so you don't need that `found` flag.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, an else clause on the for wouldn't help in this case. The questioner doesn't want to break out of the loop when the first match is found - s/he wants to continue matching further cases.

Comment: @Vicky: oops my bad - should get me another coffee I think <g>

Answer (score 1):

if I understand what you want to achieve, here is a way to do it:

```
def find_acronym():
    found=False
    # if search term in database returns acronym and expansion
    for abbr, text in acronyms.items():
        if abbr == search_analyte.get():
            found=True
            expansion.insert(0.0,'{0:>6}: {1: <10}\n'.format(abbr, text))
        elif str(search_analyte.get()) in text:
            found=True
            expansion.insert(0.0,'{0:>6}: {1: <10}\n'.format(abbr, text))

    # if search term not in database , returns message DOES NOT WORK PROPERLY!     
    if not found:
        expansion.insert(0.0,'"{0}"{1} \n {2}\n'.format(search_analyte.get(),' is  not in the database.','Add,if appropriate'))
```